# Post com form + string

Tags: javascript, c#, post

Possuo a seguinte function:

```
var form = $("#formEditarCompra");
var meioPublicacao = $("#MeioPublicacao").val();

    if (form.valid() && setarFocoErro()) {
        mostrarAguarde();
        $.post(form.attr("action"), { compra: form.serialize(), tipoMeioPublicacao: meioPublicacao }, function(data) {
            var result = data;
            if (result.Erro) {
                mostrarAlerta(result.ErroMsg, 3, "erro");
            } else {
                mostrarAlerta(result.SucessoMsg, 5);
                gridCompra.fnDraw();
            }

            esconderAguarde();
        });
    }
```

E na Controller a seguinte Action:

```
public ActionResult Editar(Compra compra, string tipoMeioPublicacao);
```

No `post` eu não consigo fazer com que as duas variaveis fiquem preenchidas, dá forma que está na function, somente o tipoMeioPublicacao vai preenchido e a Compra fica null. Tentei utilizar um objeto serializado também, da seguinte forma:

```
var compraEditar = {
        compra: form.serialize(),
        tipoMeioPublicacao: meioPublicacao
}
$.post(form.attr("action"), JSON.stringify(compraEditar), function (data)
```

Desta forma, a Compra vai preenchida, porém o tipoMeioPublicacao  vai null.

Como fazer para enviar tudo no `post`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você faz um `.serialize()` ele gera uma querystring, para adicionar parametros nela você pode usar umas das seguintes formas:

```
(form.serialize() + ("&tipoMeioPublicacao=" + meioPublicacao));
```

Ou você pode utilizar o `$.param()` que acho mais elegante:

```
var parametro = {
   tipoMeioPublicacao: meioPublicacao
};

(form.serialize() + '&' + $.param(parametro));
```

Depois basta passar o valor direto pelo seu `$.post()`:

```
var parametrosPost = (form.serialize() + '&' + $.param(parametro));

$.post(form.attr("action"), parametrosPost , function (data) {
 //seu metodo
});
```

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado pela resposta. ^^